# multiple sql auto increment (AI) counters - one that resets after every n entries - increment only on insert

Tags: php, sql

I'm using mysql and php.

I'm doing a type of user drawing entry where I take a users information and store it in a mysql database. Currently the database is setup with a unique column from eliminated people from entering multiple times.

What I would like to do is allow them to re-enter after "n" other entries have been submitted. I plan to pull the last "n" entries with php and run a regex. If they aren't able to re-enter I would like to tell them what spot they are at.

**Current Database:**

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Extra
idp     int(30) NO      PRI auto_increment
url     varchar(250)    NO  UNI     
name    varchar(250)    NO  UNI     
date    timestamp       NO  on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This is my current query to grab last "n" records:

```
SELECT url FROM mytable order by idp desc limit 50
```

My thought is that a second counter in my database would be the best solution that resets every "N" entries. Is this possible? I'm still  bit of a novice with PHP so hoping I can find a solution I can manage.

My other concern is that my current counter increments even when someone attempts to add an entry but isn't able to because a field is not unique. Is there a way to only count when a field is actually inserted into the database?

Comment: can you show you mysql table?

Comment: Have you tried anything (codewise) so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you give us more details we can help more.  But from what I know so far, ou could do something like this:

```
//userInput = What the user types in

//x = select ID from users table where userInfo = userInput sort Desc Limit 1
//y = select ID from users table sort DESC Limit 1
//if y-x > 999
    //enter in the database
//else
    //Echo "You have to wait for ".999 - (y-n)." more contestants.";
```